# Pyinstaller ignores dll which is part of a dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am creating a slim Python project which is wrapping a native dll, so that other Python developers can use the functionality of this dll without bothering about C-internals. This project can be build into a wheel, it can be pip installed, and it can be successfully used within scripts. However, when bundled with pyinstaller, the dll is ignored, so the bundled program crashes.

I know there is a workaround by explicitly telling pyinstaller to include the dll: `pyinstaller --add-binary="source/path/mylib.dll:destination/path ./main.py`. However, this somewhat defies the purpose of such a wrapper which is to obfuscate the dll's existence to the user. I would like to know if there is a way to improve my wrapper's project structure so that pyinstaller will find the dll automatically.

---

This is how my wrapper project is structured:

```
wrapper
|-- wrapper
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- mylib.dll
|-- pyproject.toml
```

`pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "wrapper"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
import ctypes
import importlib.resources as res

lib = None
with res.path("wrapper", "mylib.dll") as dll_path:
  lib = ctypes.CDLL(str(dll_path))

# now defining several python functions accessing lib
```

As mentioned above, this project can be successfully build to a wheel by running `poetry build`, and it also can be installed by `pip install <wheel name>`. In both cases, the dll gets recognized and copied to the proper direction (like e.g. site-packages/wrapper). Having it installed, the following script runs successfully:

`main.py`:

```py
import wrapper

# calling arbitrary functions from the wrapper module
```

However, when running `pyinstaller ./main.py`, the library `mylib.dll` is ignored, and the bundled executable crashes with a `PyInstallerImportError`.

---

**Added later:** Running `pyinstaller --collect-binaries wrapper .\main.py` actually works fine. This is a solution which isn't too bad for my taste. As a library developer however, I would still prefer a solution which does not require users to set nonstandard flags to be able to use my library. So I am looking forward for better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PyInstaller team was leading me to [PyInstaller hooks](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html), and this is exactly what I needed. There is a very [general example](https://github.com/pyinstaller/hooksample) demonstrating many features of those hooks. In my case, I needed to change my project structure in the following way:

```
wrapper
|-- wrapper
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- mylib.dll
|   |-- __pyinstaller
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- hook-wrapper.py
|-- pyproject.toml
```

The newly added files look like that:

`__init__.py`:

```py
import os

def get_hook_dirs():
    return [os.path.dirname(__file__)]
```

`hook-wrapper.py`:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('wrapper', excludes=['__pyinstaller'])
```

I also had to add one extra section to my `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "wrapper"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.plugins.pyinstaller40]
hook-dirs = "wrapper.__pyinstaller:get_hook_dirs"
```

Now any script using my wrapper library can be bundled just by running `pyinstaller <script name>`.